# Netbeans JAX-WS Generated Classes Collisons (stub and server on the same project)

Tags: web-services, soap, netbeans, jax-ws, wsimport

I'm developing two server-side independent modules (A and B).

B interacts with A as a client. So far so good.

The problem is that when I generate the stub on B, Netbeans generates the classes in a different package turning the same class incompatible with the rest (Although they are the same class).

```
public RegistryResponseType documentRepositoryProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetB(ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequestType body) 
{
    oasis.names.tc.ebxml_regrep.xsd.rim._3.SubmissionObjectRequest receivedObj body.getSubmitObjectsRequest();
    pt.ieeta.xadi.core.SubmitObjectsRequest stubObj = handleSubmissionObject(receivedObj);
}
```

Currently I'm translating the object (although they are the same class but generated through different processes) with the method:

```
pt.ieeta.xadi.core.SubmitObjectsRequest stubObj = handleSubmissionObject(receivedObj);
```

I bet there is a straightforward way to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance and Sorry for being JAX-WS noob ;)

Comment: How are you generating these classes ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are starting with wsdl and generating the classes...
Don't generate the classes in two separate processes. Set up a third project to contain the generated code (and nothing else). Then the other two projects reference the output of that -- either as a project dependency, or by generating a jar and sharing a common artifact. Of course, this assumes that both of your server side applications will be using compatible runtimes (not necessarily the same container, but at least both supporting the same version of JAX-WS specification, which also matches the tools in your development environment).